# Learn a framework on a project, or mix languages between backend services

Tags: java, python, programming-languages, spring, django

I am designing my next project, which will do various domain-specific tasks, but all that will be controlled and used via a generic crud web app.

I have been professionally using Java with Spring for over 3 years now with the usual corporate applications, but these domain-specific tasks absolutely have to be done in Python. I was already going to split the "core" app from these modules, but now I am wondering if I should go for Java core with Python modules communicating over REST or queues, or try to write the core app in Django and enjoy potentially better integration and easier codebase in case I would work on it with someone else in the future.

The whole point of this dilemma is because I'm a mid-level Java dev, and while I can write Python (these adapters will be small-ish so not a problem), I never used it professionally nor written any Django project before. The deadline is not exactly tight and I don't mind learning, but I want to do this seriously, and I'm not sure benefits of which side outweigh the other.

Tl;dr: pro Java/amateur python dev wants to write an application that needs a crud web app core and python adapters. Is learning Django worth a hassle or should I stick to Spring and have different languages in different backend modules?

Comment: I don't think this is sensibly answerable from this 30.000 feet view, since we have no idea how much your system will really benefit by *"better integration and easier codebase"*. And even if we would know your requirements and constraints in-depth, decisions like that usually stay opinionated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> these domain-specific tasks absolutely have to be done in Python

Until you also find something that "absolutely has to be done" in Java as well, don't impose your personal bias on the project.

Yes, learning is slow. But have some respect for maintenance. When you use Spring and Java together you're ensuring that the code base needs someone who knows both to maintain it. But at least that's a common pairing. You're proposing Java and Spring and Python and Django. When it could just be Python and Django.

I'm a polyglot. I can work in multiple languages. But even I shudder at the thought of mixing all this together. Jumping from language to language is distracting. Take the time to learn how to build this in Python. You may find it does better at this than you think.

As Doc Brown cautions below, there may be justifications for mixing. You've identified a personal bias for Java. Rather than forbidding mixing, I'm advising you check that impulse and instead put the projects needs ahead of your own.

Comment: I don't see much personal bias in the question. The OP is a lot more experienced in Java/Spring than in Django/Python, and has no idea how long it will take them to learn the latter. Sounds quite factual, not very biased. The OP also did not tell us much about their organization, if the domain-specific tasks and the core app will be maintained by the same person or by a team. So all-in-all, though I share your opionion about not mixing too many different technologies in one project, I think it is not a good idea to give the OP advice based on that restricted information we have.

Comment: @DocBrown Choosing Java because you know Java isn't injecting a personal bias?

Comment: Choosing Java because *I like Java more than Python* would be personal bias. Choosing a programming language environment for which I know I can implement something within, lets say, less than 3 weeks vs. choosing another one for which I don't know how long it will take is a question of risk management. And the fact the OP asked here shows to me they actually want to avoid to make a biased decision.

Comment: @DocBrown risk is something to respect for maintenance as well.

Comment: Absolutely! As I said, I share your opinion about not mixing too many technologies. But sometimes this can be justified, and I think based on that minimum of information we got about the OPs case, it it more likely our personal bias against a technology mix makes us jumping to premature conclusions.

Comment: @DocBrown the bias against mixing isn't personal. OP could be dead and the mix lives on and now requires a complicated job listing.

Comment: @DocBrown better?

Comment: Well, I still think it is better not to answer questions like this at all, at least not based on so few information. Where I agree is: when the OP has the time to learn Django, they should do it. Then they can answer the question if that "was worth the hassle" or if that environment is a viable alternative to Java/Spring for their use case by themselves.

Comment: Thank you guys for the insightful discussion. I wanted to omit details to prevent oversharing and an unrelated wall of text. The project will be initially, and maybe forever maintained by me - it's going to be my first "serious" personal project and if lucky, a startup maybe? I had worries about learning Django since I will also have to heavily upgrade my front-end skills. Also something I didn't think about was to quickly(ish) develop a prototype/MVP in spring, and then later on, especially when performance motivated, rewrite existing code to Python/Django.

Comment: @rafal.sz: I am sure "performance" will never be a justification to switch between Spring and Django. The point is: in a larger organization with one team responsible for Web apps written with Spring, and another team for domain-specific tasks with Python (maybe some scientists using SciPy, NumPy and Pandas), maintenance will probably be simpler by staying with these two technologies (which is almost 100% contrary to this answer). In a smaller team, or even more for a solo dev, responsible for the whole system, this answer is 100% right: avoid mixing the technologies if you can.....

Comment: ... so if I were in your shoes, with the expectation of doing all the maintenance alone, I would take the time to learn about Django first up to the degree you can make your own assessment of both tech stacks.

Comment: @DocBrown "simpler by staying"? I saw nothing to indicate a single line of code had been written yet.

Comment: @candied_orange: well, the OP wrote *"domain-specific tasks absolutely have to be done in Python."* This seems to be an external requirement for which it is not unreasonable to assume its goal is to incorporate *existing* Python modules written or maintained by some other team of the OP's organization. give them a REST interface and control the by a Web app. Note I have no idea if that's the OPs case, but it is a possble scenario. As I wrote, the OP should have given us more context (especially organizational context), currently, it leaves us just guessing around.

Comment: The external requirement is essentially usage of several scientific/engineering libraries that exist only in Python (to be perfectly blunt, my entire niche is knowing when and how to use them, and at the same time having professional experience in web apps).

Since the tasks I want to do with these (with my own code) can be entirely separated into separate microservices which only communicate with the core web app (I can just plop a Flask webserver on top of the domain code), the mixing of the languages/frameworks is even possible. The "performance" here == communication between services.

Comment: @rafal.sz still sounds like the only existing code is in those libraries. My point remains, mixing comes with a cost. One that remains long after your personal issues are gone. You must decide if that cost is worth paying for the expediency of letting you work in your familiar language today. You said "the deadline is not exactly tight and I don't mind learning". The cost is time. The benefit is avoiding the mix. You were hoping the language/stack were different enough to make the choice obvious. They aren't. Either can solve the problem.

Comment: @rafal.sz it might be worth asking about these costs. You likely aren't the only one who will be dealing with them.